# Django view of filenames in PyDev

Tags: django, aptana, pydev

Quick question: sometimes, when I have a similar file from two or more apps open, PyDev shortens the tab name to something like "views.py | app1" and "views.py | app2". Sometimes, it just gives me the whole filepath. Is there a way to force the first view?